# How to manage an object according to the lifecycle of the app pool in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, object, iis-7, static, dispose

Basically, what I'm trying to do is create a singleton object that lasts for as long as the app pool is alive.

IIS should be able to instantiate and destroy many applications which can can all access the singleton object.

So far, it sounds like a static class should do the job right? The only complication is that I want to dispose it when the app pool shuts down.

Comment: What would you be looking to do in your dispose method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a finalizer:

```
public class MyClass
{ 
    public MyClass() 
    { 
        //Constructor 
    } 

    ~MyClass() 
    { 
        // Deconstructor/finalizer 
    } 
}
```